# How to rename FK in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Trying to rename foring key in MS SQL using

```
sp_rename 'FK_Catalog_Equipment__Equiements_Catalog_Client_Clients','FK_Catalog_Equipment__Equipments_Catalog_Client_Clients','OBJECT'
```

or

```
sp_rename 'Table_Name.FK_Catalog_Equipment__Equiements_Catalog_Client_Clients','FK_Catalog_Equipment__Equipments_Catalog_Client_Clients','OBJECT'
```

but both commands result in

```
Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 359
Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong.
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: You don't need to pass the `@objtype` parameter

Comment: Is the FK created in the `dbo` schema or some other schema?

Comment: you are right.
adding schema name before FK name solved the problem.
But in this case there is another question:
why this variation doesn't work?
`sp_rename 'Catalog.Table.FK_Name','New_Name','Object';`

Comment: Foreign key constraints are individual objects, which is why you can't have a FK with the same name as other objects. Therefore, their name is relevant to the schema

Answer (score 26):

Foreign key constraints are individual objects, which is why you can't have a FK with the same name as other objects. Therefore, their name is relevant to the schema.

Copying from [sp_rename's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx) example:

```
sp_rename 'HumanResources.FK_Employee_Person_BusinessEntityID', 'FK_EmployeeID';
```

will rename `FK_Employee_Person_BusinessEntityID` found in the `HumanResources` schema to `FK_EmployeeID`

If the schema is missing, SQL Server looks for objects in the user's default schema, which is often the `dbo` schema. If the FK is created in a different schema, you need to specify it explicitly

Comment: in this case I receive the message: 
    `No item by the name of 'FK_...' could be found in the current database 'DBName', given that @itemtype was input as '(null)'.`

Also tried
`sp_rename 'TableName.FK_Name', 'New_FK_Name','OBJECT';`

but in this case have the message like in my question description:
`Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (OBJECT) is wrong.`

Comment: The name should include the schema, not the table.

Comment: If the foreign key has a name including `.`, this will not work. You have to wrap the key name in brackets, e.g: `exec sp_rename '[FK_A.B.C]', 'A.B.C.D', 'OBJECT';`

Comment: @JAM that's the case where the doctor says *Don't* do that. Yes you can, but let's say, your coworkers won't be happy with you

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it's just an example - had this case just now and I got an error due to `.` in the existing FK-name. Enclosing the key in brackets solved it for me.

Comment: Primary Keys & Indexes shall use TableName.PK_Name. Foreign Key shall use Schema.FK_Name

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
 exec sp_rename '<SchemaName>.FK_Catalog_Equipment__Equiements_Catalog_Client_Clients',
 'FK_Catalog_Equipment__Equipments_Catalog_Client_Clients', 'object'
```

For more details [click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx)

Otherwise Dropping the constraint, then rename, then add the constraint back is one easy way. The cost though is huge, because creating the new constraint will have to validate the existing data.

```
    ALTER TABLE <TableName>
        DROP FOREIGN KEY 'FK_Catalog_Equipment__Equiements_Catalog_Client_Clients',
        ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Catalog_Equipment__Equipments_Catalog_Client_Clients` 
FOREIGN KEY (`<tag_id>`) REFERENCES `tags` (`<id>`);
```

Comment: No need to *drop* an object just to rename it

Comment: I am not aware rename will work or not. But this way we can achieve the answer

Comment: Just because the end result is the same doesn't mean this is a good solution. The cost though is huge, because creating the new constraint will have to validate the existing data.

Answer (score 1):

As @JAM pointed out in a comment, if your foreign key contains a `.` you need to escape the foreign key name.

This can be done in one of two ways:

```sql
EXEC sp_rename '[FK_dbo.Labs_dbo.Users_UserId]', 'FK_Labs_Users_UserId'
```

Or,

```sql
declare @fk varchar(max) = QUOTENAME('FK_dbo.Labs_dbo.Users_UserId')
EXEC sp_rename @fk, 'FK_Labs_Users_UserId'
```

And, if you're like me and are using migrations, in your `down` script don't add quotes to the second parameter.

If you quote the second parameter, the new foreign key name will incorrectly be `[FK_dbo.Labs_dbo.Users_UserId]` instead of `FK_dbo.Labs_dbo.Users_UserId`

Your `down` script should like like this:

```sql
EXEC sp_rename 'FK_Labs_Users_UserId', 'FK_dbo.Labs_dbo.Users_UserId'
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend the accepted answer, watch **not to include the schema in the second parameter**, like:

```sql
sp_rename 'dbo.FK_Employee_Person_BusinessEntityID', 'dbo.FK_EmployeeID';
```

In this case the actual name of the index will be `dbo.FK_EmployeeID` and to revert the renaming you would have to use

```sql
-- [] are important
sp_rename 'dbo.[dbo.FK_EmployeeID]', 'FK_Employee_Person_BusinessEntityID';
```